# Need help with this logic

Tags: java

I am stuck with a logic problem here. I did a lot of thinking but I cant come up with a solution. 
      So this application displays a table, My task was to add another table(BOTTOM) similar to one already present(TOP). This application is 5 years old and all the HTML and Javascript code(for sorting) are generated on the fly by Java classes. 
  Process of execution is: first it calls getData(), than populateData() which eventually calls createTable method with parameters List Data, String strURL, boolean headerRow, boolean altRowColor. `createTable(rows, url, bHdrRow, bAltColor)` 
Here the variable strURL is the HTML link for First column fields. Requirement is that if a particular link(First column) is clicked on any of the two tables, the other table should execute the same way. (For example if LINK_1 takes TOP table one level down, than on clicking it BOTTOM table should move down one level as well.
How do I make it work with Java. I dont want to go through triggering an onClick even for the tables.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is completely refreshed (no ajax) why don't you just execute that "one level down" action on both tables on the server side and render the result accordingly?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I didnt really get it. Page is refreshed completely (There is no ajax involved), but for both the tables Links are completely independent of each other.

Comment: Yes, but the tables need to be linked somehow, otherwise what you want to achieve doesn't make sense for me. For example: both tables represent the employees in some company and for a given hierarchy level. If you now click a link you get the employees whose boss that person is. So line 1 in table 1 and line 1 in table 2 are related and represent the same person. If you load new data for table 1 you'd also load new data for table 2. So when you subsequently render both tables, they should still match.

Comment: or maybe just use javascript and use onClick event inclusively for both the tables?

Comment: Thomas, you described it perfectly. Do you think Javascript solution would work well here? Once the page is generated, I'll have access to all the links.

Comment: I'm not sure the Javascript solution would work, since you would generate 2 submits that should yield the same data. Plus if one of the submits hangs/fails, and you update the data for just one table, you'd get inconsistent views.